# How to write new nodes in a RDF document with Apache Jena?

Tags: java, rdf, jena

I want to add new nodes to my RDF document, the first time I made the document I write something like:

```
    String eventosURI = "http://Eventos";
    String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "DataBase/Events.xml";
    Model base = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    Resource node = base.createResource(eventosURI).addProperty(VCARD.NAME, something);
    try{
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
        base.write(fos);
    } catch(Exception e){
        out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

But then I have to add more nodes to the same document, if I call the same servlet re-create the model and overwrites the other nodes.

I try changing the FileOutputStream with this:

```
    FileWriter write = new FileWriter(path, true);
    base.write(write);
```

This works but not the way I want because write the entire structure again... Is there any way to add nodes to a RDF already created?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to load the model from the original file into memory, add some data to the in-memory model, and then write the model back out to the file?

Comment: Alternatively, if you serialize your data in the N-Triples format, you can add more data to a file simply by _appending_ the output to the file.

Answer (score 1):

ModelFactory.getDefaultModel() creates an empty in-memory model. If you want to edit an existing model, you need to load it first.

You have several ways of doing this.

One is to use [Model.read(InputStream, String, String)](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#read%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). This takes an InputStream to an existing model, the base URI for relative URIs in the graph and the serialization language (RDF/XML is the default, it also supports TURTLE and N-TRIPLE). The method will add all statements to the model:

```
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
if (path.exists()) {
    model.read(new FileInputStream(path), null, "TURTLE"); // or whatever format you used
}
```

You will then have all the statements you previously saved in your model.